# Is it possible with JavaScript or jQuery to record embeded YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, embed, record

I have embeded 3 youtube videos and would like to add functionality to my page to record the videos into an mp3 or wwav file.  Is this possible to create this with javascript html5 or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

No. Not unless that javascript talks to some web service that will do the work for you.